# PScredentials Overload error

Tags: powershell

Im using invoke command to delete a service on a remote vm.

Im using the PScredentials for passing credentials in the invoke command.

Im getting my User and Password from an XML file.

When im running the script with only 1 remote vm theres no problem.

When im trying to run the script on more then 1 remote vm (With a foreach loop) i get an error :

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument 
count: "2".
At line:17 char:15
+ ... redential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($use 
...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], 
MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft
.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I isolated the issue to a small script that im posting :

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "PUT Your Path Here" 
$vmList = $xml.configuration.vmList



forEach ($vm in $vmList) {

$vmUser = $vm.vm.vmUser
$vmPass = $vm.vm.vmPass



#Creating PScredentials
$password = $vmPass | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = $vmUser
$credential = New-Object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

Echo $credential

}
```

The XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <vCenterServerName>Server IP</vCenterServerName>
    <vCenterUser>server user</vCenterUser>
    <vCenterPass>Server pass</vCenterPass>
    <localTempDirectory>Your Local Host</localTempDirectory>
    <vmList>
        <vm>
            <vmName>VMname</vmName>
            <vmIP>Put Server IP</vmIP>
            <vmUser>User</vmUser>
            <vmPass>pass</vmPass>
            <vmTargetFolder>Put Your Path</vmTargetFolder>
               </vm>
        <vm>
            <vmName>VMname</vmName>
            <vmIP>Put Server IP</vmIP>
            <vmUser>User</vmUser>
            <vmPass>pass</vmPass>
            <vmTargetFolder>Put Your Path</vmTargetFolder>
               </vm>
    </vmList>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have any later in the script that casts `$password` or `$username`? What happens if you put `Remove-Variable password` and `Remove-Variable username` before you define them in the loop?

Comment: I use them for another invoke command later in the script...

Answer (score 0):

Ive found the problem... Just for anyone who reads it in the future the issue was my indentation to the xml file.

I didnt called the right place.